# error instantiating a viewcontrolelr modally via code

Tags: swift, instance, modalviewcontroller

why with this code, outlets in second view controller are unwrapped as the were nil crashing the app? they even are not appearing. issue happens if I try to access the outlets, but not if I change the view's background.

in view controller 1 button:

```
let vc = SecondViewController.self.createAcertainCustomAppearenceOfVC()
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

in second view controller

```
final class func createAcertainCustomAppearenceOfVC() -> SecondViewController {
        let VC = SecondViewController()
        VC.view.backgroundColor = .systemRed
//        VC.tappedSecondOut.setTitle("push", for: .normal)
        VC.tappedSecondOut.backgroundColor = .black
        return VC
    }
```

Comment: Outlets connected to a storyboard?  If so, you need to instantiate the view controller from the storyboard.

Comment: yes outlets from storyboard, but how to call createAcertainCustomAppearenceOfVC instantiating from storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to instantiate a view controller that has outlets in a storyboard, you need to instantiate the controller from both the storyboard name and the view controller's identifier that is set in Interface Builder.

```
final class func createAcertainCustomAppearenceOfVC() -> SecondViewController? {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewControllerIdentifier") as? SecondViewController
}
```

[image: Interface Builder]

Comment: how to set button title, to label's text?

Comment: That's not what you asked

Comment: What is the name of your storyboard file?

Comment: "secondStoryboard"

Comment: Then you need to change the storyboard instantiation as `UIStoryboard.init(name: "secondStoryboard", bundle: nil)`